# How to use Eclipse TPTP project example

Tags: eclipse

I've installed Eclipse TPTP and the TPTP project examples. I am pretty sure the TPTP project examples contains a number of ready-to-use examples. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get those examples. Could anyone please shed a light on this?

Comment: TPTP is dead. Try VisualVM if you want profiling.

Comment: I think the last version that is supported is Helios, Eclipse 3.6, so it could still work. But your best bet is to use some other program. Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool, http://www.eclipse.org/mat/, is another one you may want to look at.

Comment: Thanks guys. Will try VisualVM as @artbristol suggested.